# How much damage do I have to inflict onto an enemy to still get XP even if a companion/someone other than me finishes them off?

Tags: fallout-4

Sometimes I put quite a few bullets into an enemy, someone/something else kills them, and I still get XP for it. Other times I put quite a few bullets into an enemy, someone/something else kills them, and I'm not rewarded any XP.

So how much damage do I have to inflict onto an enemy to ensure I'm rewarded XP upon their death?

Comment: I've never understood how the xp system works in this regards in Fallout. I'm pretty sure there have been times where say a raider and gunner were fighting each other and I would be awarded Xp for just watching one of them die.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I'd literally just wander around, hear distant gunfire, be rewarded 17 XP, and just kinda accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [This mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/9314/?) changes the amount of damage you need to do to an enemy in order to receive xp for that enemy when it dies. **By default you need to do 25% of the total damage done to the enemy in order to gain xp.**
>
> – *Lower Damage Requirement For XP (Fixed Companion Kills)*

Comment: Thanks for giving the link to the mod but I'm on PS4 ;) Maybe someone else will find it useful tho.

Comment: @ExoMute - This mod changes the amount of damage you need deal to the enemy to 1 damage point.  By default you need to do 25%